# Handle slow rendering complex components

Tags: reactjs, optimization, web-worker

I have very slow rendering components in my project, which makes the routing very slow. Similar issue happens for the input field on entering the text as i have complex logic for the validation. How can i handle it in an efficient way.

For better understanding of the issue, sharing a codesandbox [link.](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-thunder-d18vd?file=/src/App.js)

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Take a look at code splitting and lazy loading:https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html and https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/lazy-loading

Comment: in my case the component will have only few lines of code, but let's say it is processing big array of something and taking so much time to render the component. I am not sure how code splitting and lazy loading works here to fix the issue

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. lazy load a component which should do the data processing and while it's loading you can render your fallback.

Comment: If you don't want to wait, you can structure your code so the lazy loading is done on the parent component.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the performance issue using web workers, for that I used one wrapper library for web worker, *@koale/useworker*.

Here is the codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-ptolemy-s8s94?file=/src/utils/wateCycleComponent.js)